# Why I cannot import pywin32 library that is in my pip list?

Tags: python, pywin32

I have just installed **pywin32** library with **pip install pywin32**. I see this library in the list when I execute pip list (the version that I see there is **228**).

When I write

```
import pywin32
```

or

```
from win32clipboard import *
```

And I cant import **win32clipboard** as well. I need that library.

I get this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywin32'

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32clipboard'
```

But when I double check the pywin32 demos, they are working such as **win32clipboardDemo** in C:\Users...\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\win32\Demos

The code inside win32clipboardDemo.py is

```
# win32clipboardDemo.py
#
# Demo/test of the win32clipboard module.
from win32clipboard import *
from pywin32_testutil import str2bytes # py3k-friendly helper
import win32con
import types

if not __debug__:
    print("WARNING: The test code in this module uses assert")
    print("This instance of Python has asserts disabled, so many tests will be skipped")

cf_names = {}
# Build map of CF_* constants to names.
for name, val in list(win32con.__dict__.items()):
    if name[:3]=="CF_" and name != "CF_SCREENFONTS": # CF_SCREEN_FONTS==CF_TEXT!?!?
        cf_names[val] = name

def TestEmptyClipboard():
    OpenClipboard()
    try:
        EmptyClipboard()
        assert EnumClipboardFormats(0)==0, "Clipboard formats were available after emptying it!"
    finally:
        CloseClipboard()

def TestText():
    OpenClipboard()
    try:
        text = "Hello from Python"
        text_bytes = str2bytes(text)
        SetClipboardText(text)
        got = GetClipboardData(win32con.CF_TEXT)
        # CF_TEXT always gives us 'bytes' back .
        assert  got == text_bytes, "Didnt get the correct result back - '%r'." % (got,)
    finally:
        CloseClipboard()

    OpenClipboard()
    try:
        # CF_UNICODE text always gives unicode objects back.
        got = GetClipboardData(win32con.CF_UNICODETEXT)
        assert  got == text, "Didnt get the correct result back - '%r'." % (got,)
        assert type(got)==str, "Didnt get the correct result back - '%r'." % (got,)

        # CF_OEMTEXT is a bytes-based format.
        got = GetClipboardData(win32con.CF_OEMTEXT)
        assert  got == text_bytes, "Didnt get the correct result back - '%r'." % (got,)

        # Unicode tests
        EmptyClipboard()
        text = "Hello from Python unicode"
        text_bytes = str2bytes(text)
        # Now set the Unicode value
        SetClipboardData(win32con.CF_UNICODETEXT, text)
        # Get it in Unicode.
        got = GetClipboardData(win32con.CF_UNICODETEXT)
        assert  got == text, "Didnt get the correct result back - '%r'." % (got,)
        assert type(got)==str, "Didnt get the correct result back - '%r'." % (got,)

        # Close and open the clipboard to ensure auto-conversions take place.
    finally:
        CloseClipboard()

    OpenClipboard()
    try:

        # Make sure I can still get the text as bytes
        got = GetClipboardData(win32con.CF_TEXT)
        assert  got == text_bytes, "Didnt get the correct result back - '%r'." % (got,)
        # Make sure we get back the correct types.
        got = GetClipboardData(win32con.CF_UNICODETEXT)
        assert type(got)==str, "Didnt get the correct result back - '%r'." % (got,)
        got = GetClipboardData(win32con.CF_OEMTEXT)
        assert  got == text_bytes, "Didnt get the correct result back - '%r'." % (got,)
        print("Clipboard text tests worked correctly")
    finally:
        CloseClipboard()

def TestClipboardEnum():
    OpenClipboard()
    try:
        # Enumerate over the clipboard types
        enum = 0
        while 1:
            enum = EnumClipboardFormats(enum)
            if enum==0:
                break
            assert IsClipboardFormatAvailable(enum), "Have format, but clipboard says it is not available!"
            n = cf_names.get(enum,"")
            if not n:
                try:
                    n = GetClipboardFormatName(enum)
                except error:
                    n = "unknown (%s)" % (enum,)

            print("Have format", n)
        print("Clipboard enumerator tests worked correctly")
    finally:
        CloseClipboard()

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        self.__dict__.update(kw)
    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return cmp(self.__dict__, other.__dict__)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.__dict__==other.__dict__

def TestCustomFormat():
    OpenClipboard()
    try:
        # Just for the fun of it pickle Python objects through the clipboard
        fmt = RegisterClipboardFormat("Python Pickle Format")
        import pickle
        pickled_object = Foo(a=1, b=2, Hi=3)
        SetClipboardData(fmt, pickle.dumps( pickled_object ) )
        # Now read it back.
        data = GetClipboardData(fmt)
        loaded_object = pickle.loads(data)
        assert pickle.loads(data) == pickled_object, "Didnt get the correct data!"

        print("Clipboard custom format tests worked correctly")
    finally:
        CloseClipboard()


if __name__=='__main__':
    TestEmptyClipboard()
    TestText()
    TestCustomFormat()
    TestClipboardEnum()
    # And leave it empty at the end!
    TestEmptyClipboard()
```

Comment: Hello Omer. Are you sure that you don't have several python installations. Seems like you have several ones. Can you try 'python -m pip install pywin32 && python -c "import pywin32"'

Comment: Hello Dear Guillaume. I'm getting same error as in IDLE.
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32 in c:\users...\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (228)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywin32'

Comment: This looks very much like the python you're running isn't the same python in the python37-32 dir.   What does ```python -c "import os; import sys; print(os.path.dirname(sys.executable))"``` say?

Answer (score 0):

After I uninstall and reinstall python. It solved the problem.

Thanks **Guillaume Jacquenot** and **ewong**.

I think the problem was the path. Whenever I upgrade Python, it opens a new file to the path and it confuses the IDLE.

[ImportError: No module named pywin32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50683404/importerror-no-module-named-pywin32/50684283)

And it seems that the library can be included as **import win32**, **import win32clipboard** etc. instead of **import pywin32**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using conda env then donot use only pip

Answer (score 0):

I know, its long time but may be it can help someone. I met the same problem and after I list module by help('modules'), its work, thats strange

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).